# Altering masterpage content permanently from a subpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Say I have a masterpage and 2 subpages. For sake of simplicity I'll refer the first subpage as subpage A, and the other as subpage B.

Now assume that I made a change in the masterpage label from subpage A, using the below code:

```
var lbl = this.Master.FindControl("my_control") as Label;
lbl.Text = "mynewtext";
```

It would function normally and I would see that my_control label has a different text.

However if I were to switch to subpage B, the masterpage label would change back to its initial form. I know why: Each time I load a page with a certain masterpage, the masterpage loads over and over again along with the Page_load event of the childpage. And since in the codebehind of the masterpage, the label 'my_control' has a different string value, my code alteration in subpage A disappears.

So my question is, how can I prevent that, how can I make a subpage derive the masterpage value?
OR shortly, how can I make a modification in masterpage by a subpage permanently?

Comment: You'll need some form of data storage that the master page can read when it loads, and apply the customization you've stored there. That could be session storage, a database, a file, redis, lots of options. Research and pick whatever fits your scenario the best.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way I can think, is to persist the change in some kind of storage and create the flow:

1. 1st load with a default value
2. The 1st sub page, changes the value and persists the change in a database or similar
3. The second load would take the adjusted value instead of the default.

Quick test would be to store the value into session construct.